# Akka Cluster Distibributed Pub Sub -- should I combine with eventStream?

Tags: scala, akka, publish-subscribe, akka-cluster

I’m using [Distributed Publish Subscribe](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html) as a means to publish updates in my clustered system to clients connected over Websockets. But I want my clients to begin receiving updates with minimal delay. I know from the docs that Distributed Pub Sub uses gossip to synchronize the subscriber registry across the mediators in the cluster, but what I can't figure out (because [the source for DistributedPubSubMediator](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-cluster-tools/src/main/scala/akka/cluster/pubsub/DistributedPubSubMediator.scala) is rather complex) is whether that means new subscribes might need to wait several gossip intervals to begin receiving all updates.

If this is the case, would it be a reasonable pattern create a single distributed pub sub subscriber for all my topics per cluster node, and have that actor republish these messages to the [event stream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/event-bus.html#event-stream)?